# How to apply association rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm confusing about association. 
I tried to write code below but rails was returned me "undefined method `subs'".

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @materials = @product.materials.subs
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: [ @product,@materials ]}
  end
end
```

I want Product model relates to Sub model and I get Sub model record.
If someone knows about this problem to solve please tell me.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_materials
  has_many :materials, :through => :product_materials
end

class ProductMaterial < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :material
end

class Material < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_materials
  has_many :products, :through => :product_materials
  has_many :material_subs
  has_many :subs, :through => :material_subs
end

class MaterialSub < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :material
  belongs_to :sub
end

class Sub < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :material_subs
  has_many :materials, :through => :material_subs
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@product.materials` is an array and you cannot chain a association on an array

```
@product = Product.includes(materials: :subs).find(params[:id])
@materials = @product.materials.flat_map(&:subs)
```

this will loop over the materials and will return `subs` for each `material`

Comment: `asked 1 min ago`, `answered 1 min ago` - that's pretty damn fast!

Comment: that provides to n+1, use `includes`

Comment: @BartekGładys included `:materials` & `:subs`